# Increase health when using consumable item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a inventory in my game wherein the player can equip or drink an item. In my inventory, I have potion that can use by the player. When the player uses the potion it will increase the health of the character. So, I have an error like this:  Cannot implicitly convert type void to Player. Why does I have an error like that. Really appreciate your answers guys. Thanks!

**IConsumable.cs**

```
public interface IConsumable {
    void Consume(Player player);
    void Consume(CharacterStats stats);
}
```

**ConsumableController.cs**

```
public class ConsumableController : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterStats stats;

    Player player;

    int health = 100;

    void Start() {
        stats = GetComponent<Player> ().characterStats; 
        player = GetComponent<Player> ().IncreaseHealth(health);
    }

    public void ConsumeItem(Item item) {
        GameObject itemToSpawn = Instantiate (Resources.Load<GameObject>("Consumables/" + item.ObjectSlug));

        if (item.ItemModifier) {
            itemToSpawn.GetComponent<IConsumable> ().Consume (stats);
        } else {
            itemToSpawn.GetComponent<IConsumable> ().Consume (player);
        }
    }
}
```

**PotionLog.cs**

```
public class PotionLog : MonoBehaviour, IConsumable {

    public void Consume(Player player) {
        Debug.Log ("You drank a swig of the potion. Cool!");

        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    public void Consume(CharacterStats stats) {
        Debug.Log ("You drank a swig of the potion. Rad!");

    }

}
```

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterStats characterStats;

    public int currentHealth;

    public int maxHealth;

    public PlayerLevel PlayerLevel { get; set; }

    void Awake() {
        PlayerLevel = GetComponent<PlayerLevel> ();
        //this.currentHealth = this.maxHealth;
        characterStats = new CharacterStats (5, 10, 2);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount) {
        Debug.Log ("Player takes: " + amount + " damage!");
        currentHealth -= amount;

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
            Die ();

        UIEventHandler.HealthChanged (this.currentHealth, this.maxHealth);
    }

    public void IncreaseHealth(int health) {
        currentHealth += health;

        if (currentHealth == maxHealth)
            return;

        UIEventHandler.HealthChanged (this.currentHealth, this.maxHealth);
    }

    private void Die() {
        Debug.Log ("Player dead! Reset health.");
        this.currentHealth = this.maxHealth;
        UIEventHandler.HealthChanged (this.currentHealth, this.maxHealth);
    }
}
```

Comment: And which line produces that error?

Comment: This line: player = GetComponent<Player> ().IncreaseHealth(health);

Comment: read what you wrote.. player = find the player and call something that returns void...... you either wanted player = getcomponent and then player.increasehealth.. or, not the player = at the start

Comment: I tried everything. But I can't get it. Please help me.

Comment: well I gave you the choices... what more can you expect of me?

Comment: @JohnWinslow Simply change `player = GetComponent<Player> ().IncreaseHealth(health);` to `player = GetComponent<Player> ();`. Then on another line, call your function. `player.IncreaseHealth(health);`.

Comment: @bolkay which is what I already said!